# Resharper 7 'go to declaration' not working for views in MVC 5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-7.1

I have two Visual Studio 2012 solutions both using Resharper 7.1.  One of the solutions has an MVC4 project and the other one has an MVC5 project.

In the MVC4 project, within a controller I can press F12 (go to declaration) on the `View()` method and get the option to navigate to the view (rather than the source), ie:

[image: MVC4]

However if I try the same in my other project, it just brings me directly to the source for `View()` ie:

[image: MVC5]

The only difference I can think of between the project is MVC 4 / 5 as I've mentioned and both solutions are using the same global Resharper options.

There are a few other things that it does not let me do. For example in the MVC4 project, if I try and return a `View()` for an action that does not exist, it will complain and offer to create the view, however I don't get this behaviour in the MVC5 project.

I would assume that these differences are related and was wondering if there is an option I'm not seeing somewhere.

Comment: I have the same problem even with latest R# and Vs 2015